# Lista encadeada: como modificar dado de uma lista sem alterar nos demais?

Tags: python, lista, lista-encadeada

Tenho um for que me gera uma lista de lista de dados

```
lista[[...], [...]]
```

Dentro das listas "filhas" podem ou não ter outras listas

```
lista[['dado11', 'dado12', [link1]],['dado21', 'dado22', [link2]]
```

Este dado que eu representei como link pode vir ou não dentro da lista

```
lista[['dado11', 'dado12', []],['dado21', 'dado22', [link2], ['dado31', 'dado32', [link31, link32]]
```

Porém, quando eu uso o for para pegar esses "links", eu apenas sempre alimento ultima lista... Ou seja.. Na lista[0] sempre me aparece os mesmos lisks que a existem nos lista[2]..

Não sei se consegui explicar bem, mas eu realmente queria saber como setar a variável lista de links conforme minha necessidade e que alguma alteração nessa lista não influenciasse no restante dos dados já incluídos na lista mãe..

Resumindo meu código tá mais ou menos assim:

```
for linha in tmovimentos:
    texto = linha.text
    ...
    movi_anexos = []
    For link in links:
          movi_anexos.append([link.get_attribute('href'), 'out', '.pdf', data, 'tipo', texto])

    movimentacoes.append([data, texto, movi_anexos])
```

Agradeço!

Comment: Não percebi bem, gostaria de definir valores na `lista[0]` no caso da primeira lista de listas que aparece, fazer o append de outra lista, que são os links, é isso? Ficaria por exemplo `lista[0].append([link1, link2])`, desta maneira teria depois `lista[0] = ['dado11', 'dado12', [link1, link2]]`

Comment: Isso, mas por exemplo, a movi_anexos sempre vai dando append nos links que existem, então toda vez que tenho uma lista nova na lista movimentação, ele me traz os anexos das anteriores na atual.. Entende?

Answer (score 2):

A única maneira de fazer isso que você está descrevendo aqui seria você iterando a sua lista com um for e um outro for para a lista que está encadeada dentro da lista.

```
a = [["a","a","a","a"],["a","a","a","a"]]
for lista in a:
    for item in lista:
        print("item")
```

Para fazer a inserção de dados nesta lista seria da mesma maneira.

```
a = [["a","a","a","a"],["a","a","a","a"]]
for lista in a:
    lista.append(VALOR A DAR APPEND)
```

Answer (score 1):

Então -
o que você quer fazer está confuso
COmo voce está fazendo está confuso (você põe um código "mais ou menos assim", mas que não tem tudo o que está acontecendo) - e você poderia ter dado algum exmeplo concreto de como ficam seus dados.

Mas, por fim, o trecho de código que você apresnetou aí *não deveria* apresentar o problema que você descreve.

O seu problema é o seguinte: você está inserindo o mesmo objeto (uma lista), como item de uma lista em mais de um lugar.

Se você faz isso em Python:

```
In [86]: a = ["a", ]

In [87]: b = [a, a]

In [88]: b
Out[88]: [['a'], ['a']]


In [90]: a.append("b")

In [91]: b
Out[91]: [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
```

Perceba que dentro da lista `b` a lista `a` está presente duas vezes - é o mesmo objeto. Então quando eu altero a lista `a`, é esperado que em `b` o que eu inseri apareça nos dois elementos. Nenhuma surpresa aí.

No seu código, você deve estar fazendo isso, de forma direta ou indireta. Mas no trechinho que você colou acima, isso não acontece - você recria a lista `movi_anexos` como um novo objeto, em cada iteração do seu primeiro `for`, por exemplo.

Python tem uma sintaxe que permite a você criar uma cópia de uma lista ao fazer referência a mesma que talvez possa te ajudar:
Quando for inserir uma lista como item de outra, em vez de só o nome da variável, ponha que você quer uma fatia (slice) do começo até o fim da lista que está sendo inserida (peça os elementos `[:]` um fatia omitindo os elementos inicial e final implica numa fatia do começo até fim) . Fatias de lista são cópias da lista original, e uma cópia do começo até o final é nada menos que uma cópia da lista.

Então, se você escrever código como:]
`movimentacoes.append([data, texto, movi_anexos[:])` deve evitar que a mesma lista esteja presente em mais de uma posição nas suas estruturas de dados. (mas enfatizo que no trecho que está aqui isso não acotneceria - mas não sei por exemplo se o seu `data` e `texto` são listas também - se forem, dê a eles o mesmo tratamento)

E por fim, não relacionado com a sua dúvida: a forma como você está querendo organizar esses dados parece bem problemática - você vai ter uma `sopa` de listas dentro de listas, sem comprimento definido, sem profundiade definida - parece o pior pesadelo para conseguir recuperar qualquer coisa depois.
Lembre-se de que também existem dicionários, e que, sobretudo, você pode criar suas próprias classes que vão gaurdar as suas informações de foma muito bem estruturada e podendo te ajudar bastante a trabalhar com os dados que você tem.